# VS2017 SSRS Project switch from VisualSVN to AnkhSVN

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, visualsvn, ankhsvn

I have recently upgraded from VS2008 to VS2017 and so had to upgrade VisualSVN to version 6.  Had trouble getting that working so decided to switch to AnkhSVN.

I switched my Web Site project and all works well.  Then tried my SSRS project and struck trouble.  When I go to Tools - Options and select AnkhSVN it says my solution is controlled by a different plugin and do i want to continue?  I answer yes but, when i reopen the solution, it is still set to VisualSVN. Also tried setting it to None but had the same result.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I have now uninstalled VisualSVN and things are good for my WebSite project.  But for the SSRS project, previewing a report hangs VS2017 and the first time i tried it, the server rebooted!

Comment: All fixed.  Just had to be patient.  i think it was probably rebuilding the whole project on the first preview...